# How can I add Adminer to my Ruby on Rails application with PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, adminer

I am new to ruby on rails. This question may be simple. I have been trying to add an adminer folder on the app on ruby on rails application. My database is PostgreSQL. I want to manage my database on the browser using adminer.

I wish someone could help me get an answer as to whether it's possible to add admins to a Ruby on Rails app. If you can add admins, please briefly explain how to do so. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to add a folder named adminer to your Rails app? And you want to manage your database using https://www.adminer.org/, a PHP application? And you want to add users to adminer that can then be used in Rails? This question is way too broad and unclear to be able to answer.

Comment: This should help https://gorails.com/tool_categories/admin-interfaces/tools

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.